# PHP Regex match value in between two words and replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-match-all

Hello everyone what I want to achieve with php is to find a value in between two words (for all occurances) and replace this with another string, then remove the words around the value.
Here's an example

```
$mysting = "[link]http://website.com[/link] bla bla bla bla [link]http://google.com[/link]";
```

What I want to achieve is make this string:

```
$newString = "<a href='http://website.com'>http://website.com</a> bla bla bla bla <a href='http://google.com'>http://google.com</a>";
```

How can I do this?
This is what I have for now

```
preg_match("/(?<=[link])(.*)(?=[/link])/", $formData ,$match);
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Make it non-greedy

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.bbcode-create.php http://php.net/manual/en/function.bbcode-parse.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preg_replace` function:

```
$mysting = "[link]http://website.com[/link] bla bla bla bla [link]http://google.com[/link]";
$new_str = preg_replace("/\[link\]([^\[]+)\[\/link\]/", "<a href='$1'>$1</a>", $mysting);

print_r($new_str);
```

The output(as source code):

```
<a href='http://website.com'>http://website.com</a> bla bla bla bla <a href='http://google.com'>http://google.com</a>
```